# Why is my Python for loop running out of memory?

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, memory-leaks

I have a for loop in Python/Django to iterate over a long list of users and create recommendations for them using a saved tensorflow model:

```
def create_recommendations_for_users():
    user_ids = User.objects.values_list("id", flat=True)
    retrieval_model = tf.saved_model.load("tensorflow_models/model")
    ranking_model = tf.saved_model.load("tensorflow_models/ranking_model")

    for user_id in user_ids:
        create_recommendations_for_user(user_id, retrieval_model, ranking_model)


def create_recommendations_for_user(user_id, retrieval_model, ranking_model):

    _, items = retrieval_model([user_id])

    for item_id in items[0]:
        item_id = item_id.numpy()
        rating = ranking_model.ranking_model(
            (tf.constant([user_id]), tf.constant([item_id]))
        ).numpy()

        Recommendation.objects.create(user_id=user_id, item_id=item_id, rating=rating)
```

The issue is that calling `create_items_for_users` is causing a memory leak. Why would this happen? `items` is scoped to the `create_items_for_user` function, so wouldn't this be garbage collected, as would `item_id` and `rating`, each time it gets run? `user_ids` is a long list of integers, but doesn't grow over time and isn't all that large. I'm not storing a growing list of results anywhere. Why would these functions cause a memory leak?

Comment: my recommendation would be to use `del` after every iteration. Ran into those problems multiple of times and `del` helped out a lot

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?